# Lower case URLs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to force/extend the routing engine to generate URLs in lower case, giving `/controller/action` instead of `/Controller/Action`?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. Not sure if it has any SEO implications or not, but it does look a hell of a lot better.

Answer (score 16):

What's more, you should force any incoming requests that are uppercase to be *redirected* to the lowercase version.  Search engines treat URLs case-sensitively, meaning that if you have multiple links to the same content, that content's page ranking is distributed and hence diluted.

Returning HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) for such links will cause search engines to 'merge' these links and hence only hold one reference to your content.

Add something like this to your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Don't rewrite requests for content (.png, .css) or scripts (.js)
    if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Content/") ||
        Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Scripts/"))
        return;

    // If uppercase chars exist, redirect to a lowercase version
    var url = Request.Url.ToString();
    if (Regex.IsMatch(url, @"[A-Z]"))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
        Response.AddHeader("Location", url.ToLower());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will also consider the case sensitivity of query parameters, which may or may not be an issue depending on the application (it certainly would for some things I've worked on).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just change it in the routing in the global.asax file.

@All asking if it matters: Yes I *do* think it matters.  Having the url all in lower case just looks better.

Every time you don't make something look nice when you can, Bill Buxton kills a kitten.

Comment: I think anyone who has been to Mix or ReMix in the last 12 months has had to sit through Big Billy B's (admitedly quite interesting) rant on the importance of design needing to be baked in to a product.