# How to append '/' to URL if the user removes '/' from url in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

IF this is my url `http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server`

A link in that page will became

```
http://localhost:55070/Server/2-Instance_12
```

If I change the URL like this `http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server/`

the link will be like this .`http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server/1-Instance_11`

I want seconde type (http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server/1-Instance_11/) always. If the user enters the URL like this `http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server` it may cause some issues.

If this is the URL `http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server` how can I append / to this `http://localhost:55070/Server/1-Server/`. So the links in next views are also append to it.

It is possible for user to remove the '/' and then also i need to add '/'.

This is the Razor for creating the URL.

Comment: say what? I think you might have some other issues with your links. Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt this solution [Lower case URLs in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696673/lower-case-urls-in-asp-net-mvc) to redirect the user when the url does not end with a /

Or put it in a HttpModule like so:

```
public class UrlMessingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
        var request = application.Request;
        var response = application.Response;

        var url = request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        if (url.Length > 1 && !url.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            response.Clear();
            response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            response.AddHeader("Location", url + "/");
            response.End();
        }

    }
}
```