# Does URL rewriting respect my ASP .NET MVC routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm about to normalize all the URLs in my website. I'm considering making some rewrite rules, but only if my `Html.ActionLink` code and my `RedirectToAction` code will respect those rules.

Will they? I did some early tests, and it didn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Do you plan to customize the routes in mvc to make your rewrite rules? If so it should work with `Html.ActionLink` and `RedirectToAction`

Comment: Isn't a rewriter pretty much redundant with the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL rewriting and MVC routing are completely separate processes and they don't know about each other.

If you create an ActionLink it will look at the routing map you registered in MVC and it will not look at your rewrite rules.

If you decide to add URL rewriting, you should also define the reverse rules in IIS.

Although this might work in theory, in practice I would advise you to just adapt your routing in ASP.NET MVC and not bother with URL rewriting. The routing system is flexible enough to allow almost any scenario (I haven't encountered situations it couldn't handle).

Comment: So how can I (for instance) in my routings specify that all URLs should be lowercase for normalization?

Comment: Hm, I think you may have encountered that one scenario that can't be handled by the built-in routing engine :-) This thread on SO talks about that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696673/lower-case-urls-in-asp-net-mvc
As I said, I would look into extending the routing engine instead of applying UrlRewriting, because the combination will cause you some headaches.